# iOS: how to change the direction of the view resize animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, resize, direction

I'm working on a screen in which I have a UIScrollView in it I need to provide a functionality of resizing for a UIView and UILabel. All the views are added to the UIScrollView with layout constraints.

Now to change the size of the UILabel I use the following code:

```
desriptionLabel.numberOfLines = desriptionLabel.numberOfLines == 0 ? 1 : 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.descriptionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

To change the view size I have created an IBOutlet for the height constraint of this view and I do the following:

```
if additionalSocialViewHeightConstraint.constant == 60 {
    additionalSocialViewHeightConstraint.constant = 240
} else {
    additionalSocialViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60
}
    
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   self.additonalSocialView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now both animations do work and resize the label and view accordingly, the problem I'm having is with the way those animations work.

in both cases, the animations expends the view from a center and out. So for the label, the view of the label grows immediately to the expected size to fit all the label text, and then the text starts to spread from one line in the center of the big view in both directions up and down.

In the case of the view. again the view first enlarges the space around it where the initial view is placed in the middle of this space and then it grows in both up and down directions to take up all the space.

**The Problem:** Now because I'm in a UIScrollView this does not look good and I need to change the animation from starting in the middle and spreading in both direction to start at the top and spread only to the bottom. Also, I need the shrinking to the original size animation to work in the same manner, meaning shrinking the view from bottom to top.

**The Question:** How should I manage this kind of animation? What am I doing wrong?

Constraints configuration for both view:

**UILabel:**

[image]

**UIView:**

[image]

Comment: It is about constraints and their priority. Seems you have center constraint now, try to add top constraint (can be strict, can be >=0 )  and make it priority high then centre, so it will be shifted down, if needed.

Comment: @MichaelV, none of those views has a center constraint in any direction, unfortunately.

Comment: They had to have something that keep them centre. Perhaps they have bottom constraint. If they have no constraints at all, perhaps it is time to add them.

Comment: @MichaelV, I added screenshots of constraints configuration for both views, as you can see I have a bottom constraint on both of them but with lower priority. Do you see here anything that can cause this animation direction?